# How to reload state using angular-ui-router?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

How to reload a controller and entire side using angular-ui-router?

```
$state.reload() or $state.go('myState')
```

does not work. Only method which works is:

```
$state.go('anotherState');
$state.go('myState');
```

- going to another state and back. Then, view is reloaded corretly. How to do it without this hack?

Regards

Comment: Do you want page refresh or not?

Comment: It is SPA application so it should not. It should only reload controller like I said

Comment: When you say 'does not work', how do you know it does not reload? If you put an $onInit() in the state's controller and console logged in there, does it give you the message? If so, it's 'working'.

Comment: @rrd I have preloader which runs when page is loading first time, I see what is on scope and if controller is reloaded

Comment: Can you post your states so we can see them, might be an error in them in $state.reload() isn't working.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this without page refresh. This will reload the view:

```
$state.transitionTo($state.current, $stateParams, {
    reload: true,
    inherit: false,
    notify: true
});
```

or else try this

```
$state.go($state.current.name,{},{reload: $state.current.name});
```

Comment: Then you need to post your HTML and route files with the ui router version you are using

Comment: i have updated the answer. Please check it and try that

Answer (score 1):

I found this to be the shortest working way to refresh with ui-router:

```
$state.go($state.current, {}, {reload: true}); //second param is for $stateParams if you have any.
```

New versions also support this:

```
$state.reload();
```

Which is an alias for:

```
$state.transitionTo($state.current, $stateParams, { 
  reload: true, inherit: false, notify: true
});       // this is also used to reload the controller and view without page reload.
```

Documentation: https://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.$state#methods_reload